# When to use Boolean(var1)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the [redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data) it says:

```
const canSave = Boolean(title) && Boolean(content) && Boolean(userId)
```

- But userId = 0 would then convert to false
- Can't you just use the following?

```
const canSave = title && content && userId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use TypeScript with `title && content && userId` expression, the expression evaluation is a `string`, the TSC will throw a type
mismatch  error, see below example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Test() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');

  return <button disabled={title && content && userId}>click me</button>;
}
```

Error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(2054, 9): The expected type comes from property 'disabled' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>'

So you need to convert the string to boolean. From the doc [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

> Do not use a `Boolean` object to convert a non-boolean value to a boolean value. To perform this task, instead, use `Boolean` as a function, or a double NOT operator:

```
var x = Boolean(expression);     // use this...
var x = !!(expression);          // ...or this
```

So the code should be:

```js
const canSave = Boolean(title) && Boolean(content) && Boolean(userId);
// or
const canSave = !!title && !!content && !!userId;
```

Both of them are ok.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but imagine you get strange result for some values for title. Imagine someone put `false` in their title or content. Not sure about userId  though

Answer (score 0):

Having to convert to Boolean explicitly would be needed in the (probably slightly unusual) case that the result is checked not for truthyness or falseyness, but against another boolean. To illustrate, the following's logic fails:

```js
const title = '';
const content = 'content';
const userId = 'foo';

const canSave = title && content && userId;
if (canSave === false) {
  console.log('cant save');
  throw new Error();
}
console.log('saving...');
```

Converting `canSave` to boolean will fix that.

But a more DRY approach would be to call `Boolean` on the whole result, instead of on every individual expression.

```
const canSave = Boolean(title && content && userId);
```

> But userId = 0 would then convert to false

Not sure what you're getting at. If that's an issue, maybe the logic you'd want is `typeof userId === 'number'`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Boolean, you can always use this shortcut instead:

```
const canSave = !!(title && content && userId)
```

But `!!` will convert it to Boolean.

Think for example you need to pass boolean from your server to client, and you don't wish to string string.